# Phase and constellation diagram

Tags: modulation, qam

I have noticed that when, for example, \$cos(t)\$ is in-phase (I) component of the modulated signal, we can determine the phase from the constellation diagram measured counterclockwise from the horizontal axis.

However, when, for example, \$sin(t)\$ is an I component of the modulated signal, we can no longer determine the phase as described above. How can we determine the phase from the constellation diagram in such case? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I & Q phases are encoded by Cos & Sin, if these are mixed up, then you are out of sync

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 For example, I found here: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Communication_Systems/Quadrature_Amplitude_Modulation that sin is I component. I am assuming this is incorrect?

Comment: Good catch. That is correct. The Sine is “In Phase”. swapping these reverses the circular direction that You described.  In higher levels of encoders , there are trellis sequences error detection sequences defined.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trellis_modulation#A_new_modulation_method

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 If Sine is "In phase", then the correct way to determine the phase from constellation diagram is by measuring it clockwise from the horizontal axis, right?

Comment: Now you understand it . this same method is used for binary Quadrature position encoders to determine position and velocity direction by detecting which pin rises first.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thank you. I have come to this conclusion by myself but wanted to check if it is correct since I am not formally electrical engineer and currently self-learning about this topic.

Comment: That’s great. For this basic trig and logic is all you need to know

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I was reviewing my notes, which I lost partially, so I tried to write down again constellation diagrams for all possible combinations of "I" and "Q" components for Sine and Cos. I used this discussion as a guideline to determine the phase from the constellation diagram. Is it possible that I made a mistake above; instead of saying "...measuring it clockwise from the horizontal axis" it should be ".... clockwise from the vertical axis"? For example, sinx+cosx yields a sine wave with phase (+pi/4) which corresponds to the angle measured clockwise from vertical axis.